# Google compute: Red hat Gui

Tags: google-compute-engine

I would understand this is not recommended for security perspective. However, if person wants to GUI if installed Red hat linux what should be the process. The one mentioned in [medium](https://medium.com/google-cloud/linux-gui-on-the-google-cloud-platform-800719ab27c5#.4re12qwys) instruction is for Ubuntu only seems.